# how to create unit vector by scaling two components

Tags: vectors

I have a 3D vector with length != 1 but all components lie within [-1, 1].

now I want to create a unit vector such that this unit vector has the same x coordinate as the original vector and the cross product between the x-axis and the new vector shall point in the same direction as the cross product between the x-axis and the original vector.

How do I need to scale the y and z coordinates to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let see, suppose the original vector is

$$v=(a,b,c)$$

and the unit vector is

$$u=(a,d,e)$$

such that

$$u \times (1,0,0)=\lambda\cdot v \times (1,0,0) \iff e \hat y-d\hat z=\lambda c \hat y-\lambda b\hat z$$

that is

$$u=(a,\lambda b,\lambda c)$$

with the condition

$$a^2+(\lambda b)^2+(\lambda c)^2=1 \implies \lambda=\sqrt{\frac{1-a^2}{b^2+c^2}}$$

Comment: so, how do I solve for λ? there should be only one solution (the one in which the vector points in the same direction, not in the opposite one)

Comment: @user1282931 By $\lambda^2=\frac{1-a^2}{b^2+c^2}$ we obtain $2$ solutions which lead to two opposite vectors for $u\times (1,0,0)$.

Comment: @user1282931 The $\lambda$ positive should be the correct one.